# Deploying NextJs to Vercel - - error ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'compat'mpat' Require stack: - /vercel/path0/__placeholder__.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have deployed a NextJs to Vercel.
Some pages work fine but others do not.
I get the following error in log

```
- error ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'compat' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-compat' Require stack: - /vercel/path0/__placeholder__.js`
```

It works well on my localhost

Here is my package.json

```json
"dependencies": {   
  "@types/node": "20.4.4",
  "@types/react": "18.2.15", 
  "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7", 
  "animate.css": "^4.1.1",   
  "aos": "^2.3.4",     
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",    
  "chartist": "^1.3.0", 
  "eslint": "8.45.0",
  "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",   
  "eslint-plugin-compat": "^4.1.4",  
  "metismenu": "^3.0.7",
  "next": "13.4.12",   
  "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4", 
  "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
  "react": "18.2.0",  
  "react-dom": "18.2.0", 
  "sass": "^1.64.1",   
  "sharp": "^0.32.4",  
  "typescript": "5.1.6"
}
```

I removed the content of ESlint gradually starting from removing only the plugin
I also removed this `// eslint-disable-line compat/compat` from font-awsome conflict-detection.js

Comment: Your error is about loading eslint-plugin-compat. Looks like it's probably in your eslintrc and you're doing something with it at build time. Please post those relevant snippets — your eslintrc and probably the `scripts` section of your package.json. You can use three backticks to properly format code as a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@types/node` dependency is `20.4.4`. Vercel only supports up to node version 18. Most likely, you are deploying with node 18. Thus, reduce `@types/nodes` version to 18